# Closure::fromCallable for imported function

Tags: php, php-7.1, php-7.2

I'm playing with PHP and some functional style programming.

I'm using the [Functional-PHP library](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php/blob/master/docs/functional-php.md#pick) but question is generic to PHP (I'm using 7.2).

I try to create a callable from an imported function but what I get is

**TypeError: Failed to create closure from callable: function 'pick' not found or invalid function name**

Sample code:

```
use function Functional\pick;

class A
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $pick1 = \Closure::fromCallable('pick');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP `use` statements define an alias for the rest of the file, but they won't affect a string referencing an imported function or class.

When you say

```
use function Functional\pick;
```

it means that in that file, you can call the `Functional\pick` function just using `pick(...)`. But if you're using a string to reference it then PHP doesn't know to expand the alias.

The quickest way to resolve this is just to use the fully qualified function name when calling `fromCallable`:

```
$pick1 = \Closure::fromCallable('Functional\pick');
echo get_class($pick1);
```

> Closure

Alternatively, if you really wanted to use the alias, you could wrap the call a level deeper with another anonymous function:

```
use function Functional\pick;

$pick1 = \Closure::fromCallable(function (...$args) { return pick(...$args); });
```

But that's a lot messier, in my opinion at least.

**Edit:** There's some decent discussion around this in [this recent thread](https://externals.io/message/103390) in php-externals

Comment: It's really unfortunate there's not an equivalent to `::class` for function names.

Comment: If you want as much static resolution as possible, you can also do `\Closure::fromCallable([Functional::class, 'pick'])`